# How to overcome politics of the net (Google translate code refuses to work from a specific region)

Tags: html, css, javascript, google-translate

According to the [FAQ's](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) I am not sure if my question is a ok to ask or will be closed or should I post it in the [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) or even I would blame some one for downvoting it. However it is one that has been bugging me since the trouble strated. Let me explain.

I have this [Web Site](http://www.pufs.org/). It uses the Google Translate API (Can't post the link, does not open from this region) with the following code.

```
<meta name="google-translate-customization" content="9f841e7780177523-3214ceb76f765f38-gc38c6fe6f9d06436-c"></meta>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit()
{
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

The problem is since [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innocence_of_muslims), it just stopped working. On the site you can see that I had to actually remove the above from [here](http://www.pufs.org/cattle.html), [here](http://www.pufs.org/fish.html), and [here](http://www.pufs.org/poultry.html) while left it [here](http://www.pufs.org/index.html), [here](http://www.pufs.org/message.html), [here](http://www.pufs.org/news.html) and [here](http://www.pufs.org/contact.html). This is so because the the web site "refuses" to load at all with the pages that have the code (i.e., from this [region](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakistan).)

If I use [Firefox Stealthy Plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stealthy/) and open the site in Firefox, It works like a charm without any problems. But with Google Chrome, Apple Safari and Opera Web browser, the site does not load/open at all because of the Google translate. (I know this because If I remove the Google Translate Code, the site works/loads fine)

It was one thing to program for "cross browser compatability" and alltogether another to program for "cross region compatability".

What can I do to make sure that the site works from anywhere? Do I completely remove the Google Translate code and just have to do without the additional functionality or Do I look for alternatives like [this](http://metaoptimize.com/qa/questions/898/is-there-a-better-alternative-to-google-translate) or according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151668/alternative-to-google-translate-api)?

Comment: I should add that It has nothing to do with the iframe of google trananslte not showing up and the translation appears to be an in-build functionalty of the website itself. Just some smart CSS coding (If I may say so myself) from myside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be your ISP is blocking the Google translate API, as some Pakistani ISPs are  [blocking google apps](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-users-in-pakistan-suffer/25734/). There might be nothing you can do except find a proxy to pass your queries through, but if translate.google.com works then try this link, see if you can load your page in Google translate url, like so:

http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=ur&sl=en&u=http://www.pufs.org/fish.html

If that will load in all browsers, you might be able to still use translation through a apache rewrite like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-ur$ http://www.google.com/translate_c?hl=ur&sl=en&u=http://www.pufs.org/$1 [R=302,NC]
```

where a normal url will be English, and any url ending in -ur will be Urdu (or use a different hl= lang code if you want different translation) like

English
http://www.pufs.org/fish.html

Urdu:
http://www.pufs.org/fish.html-ur

once on the translated site, you shouldn't need further -ur in your urls as the links should stay within the context of the google translate frame. Hope this helps!