# How to overcome politics of the net (Google translate code refuses to work from a specific region)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-translate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to overcome politics of the net (Google translate code refuses to work from a specific region)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34903/how-to-overcome-politics-of-the-net-google-translate-code-refuses-to-work-from)

I have this [Web Site](http://www.pufs.org/). It uses the Google Translate API (Can't post the link, does not open from this region) with the following code.

```
<meta name="google-translate-customization" content="9f841e7780177523-3214ceb76f765f38-gc38c6fe6f9d06436-c"></meta>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit()
{
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

The problem is since [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innocence_of_muslims), it just stopped working. On the site you can see that I had to actually remove the above from [here](http://www.pufs.org/cattle.html), [here](http://www.pufs.org/fish.html), and [here](http://www.pufs.org/poultry.html) while left it [here](http://www.pufs.org/index.html), [here](http://www.pufs.org/message.html), [here](http://www.pufs.org/news.html) and [here](http://www.pufs.org/contact.html). This is so because the the web site "refuses" to load at all with the pages that have the code (i.e., from this [region](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakistan).)

If I use [Firefox Stealthy Plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stealthy/) and open the site in Firefox, It works like a charm without any problems. But with Google Chrome, Apple Safari and Opera Web browser, the site does not load/open at all because of the Google translate. (I know this because If I remove the Google Translate Code, the site works/loads fine)

It was one thing to program for "cross browser compatability" and alltogether another to program for "cross region compatability".

What can I do to make sure that the site works from anywhere? Do I completely remove the Google Translate code and just have to do without the additional functionality or Do I look for alternatives like [this](http://metaoptimize.com/qa/questions/898/is-there-a-better-alternative-to-google-translate) or according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151668/alternative-to-google-translate-api)?